# subscript property using enum String failing with 'Cannot assign value of type <enumType> to type AnyObject'

Tags: swift, enums, swift-subscript

I've got a class with a subscript property (it inherits from another class that takes type 'AnyObject' in a subscript).

```
public var payFrequency: PayFrequency {
    get { return self["payFrequency"] as? PayFrequency ?? .Weekly }
    set(value) { self["payFrequency"] = value }
}
```

The compiler complains that I:

> ```
> Cannot assign value of type 'PayFrequency' to type AnyObject
> ```

When I try to cast `value` to `AnyObject`:

```
set(value) { self["payFrequency"] = value as? AnyObject }
```

...it compiles, but fails to set the value to anything (when I get the variable, it always returns the default `.Weekly`).

Here's the enum:

```
public enum PayFrequency: String {
    case Weekly = "weekly"
    case SemiMonthly = "semi-monthly"
    case BiWeekly = "bi-weekly"
    case Monthly = "monthly"
}
```

How can I get this enum to work with AnyObject, OR how can I update the getter/setter of the subscript to properly store the enum value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AnyObject` is not compatible with enums, as enums are value types, while `AnyObject` corresponds to a reference.

You can try using `NSString` for the enum declaration, and use it's raw value within the property.

```
public enum PayFrequency: NSString {

public var payFrequency: PayFrequency {
    get { return PayFrequency(rawValue: self["payFrequency"] as? String ?? "") ?? .Weekly }
    set(value) { self["payFrequency"] = value.rawValue }
}
```

or keep the enum declaration the same, Swift should be able to bridge between `String` and `NSString`.

Comment: Hrm, nope, the getter is still returning `nil`. If I print `self["payFrequency"] as? String`, I do see the string value of the enum there, but how can I convert the string value back into the type enum?

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't try and use strings for this; if I did an enum using integer, is there a way I can store the Int with the superclass and write the getter to return the enum type for the specified Int?

Comment: Nice! Good catch on the cast to String and checking for bad types too.